# Eclipse Indigo shows Kepler loading screen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I recently downloaded eclipse Indigo after abandoning Kepler because of all the bugs. Almost everything is fine except the loading screen for Indigo is still Kepler. The version of Eclipse IS in fact indigo (I checked About Eclipse for that), but I'm concerned if Indigo might be mixed with Kepler for some reason. After noticing some bugs on Indigo that are Kepler-specific, I re-extracted the files of Indigo, and all those bugs went away, except for the Kepler loading screen. Just concerned if Kepler might have passed on more than its loading screen to Indigo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just some resources folder that's located outside of the app folder. It shouldn't matter for functionality.

Comment: Probably. Haven't ran in to any functional issues with Indigo like I have with Kepler now. Thanks for your help.